# Make all objects of a model available to another model

Tags: python, django

If I have the following models:

```
class Player(models.Model):
  game = models.ForeignKey('Game', null=True, blank=True)

class Game(models.Model):
  score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

This way,  if I have multiple objects of type game, p.game (where p is an object of type Player) will always be None. If I add n objects of type Game, I want them to be available to all players, but each player should have his own score. How can I achieve this?  Django 1.4.2 if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Django ManyToManyField is the answer:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

UPDATE: scores can be extra field in M2M like here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: I still have to add each game to each player manually. It's not what I need

Comment: If we avoid looking into visualisation, with many to many you have
Game - list of games, visible for all players,
Players.game - part of all games choosen for every player (can be unique)
So problem is with UI?

Comment: Ah sorry, just see those scores

Comment: ok, then manytomany with extra fields - as here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: What happens if I have 10 players and I add 5 games? How can I get a list of all scores of each game for each player, if you don't mind explaining? (it will be 0 by default but that doesn't matter)

Comment: It create intermediate model for linkage, so in say mysql it will be three tables:
Player,PlayerGames, Games

For each player-game link there will be one PlayerGame object with some fields like score
So for 10 players, 5 games there will be 10 player records, 5 game records and N playergame records (N - player-game links)

And to count scores for Player you will need something like player.games_set. and then agregate/sum etc

Comment: Django Documentation has good example in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships about Beatles :)

Comment: And I still have to create those links manually? They aren't created by default.  (e.. g.  If I add a new game, each player should be linked with that game with score=0)

Comment: User are connected to all games by default?

Comment: @IulianRadu: No the relations won't be created "by default", hopefully. It's quite easy to add some code to do so when either a new game or player is created (using django's signals) but you may want to wait until you have a need for it (ie: a score to save) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create third model and keep it simple.

```
class Player(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(default="John Rambo", max_length=256)

class Game(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(default="Pack-man", max_length=256)

class Instance(models.Model):
  player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
  game = models.ForeignKey(Game)
  score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I see you're very beginner so adding an example:

```
In [1]: from xyz.models import *

In [2]: player = Player()
In [3]: player.save()

In [4]: game = Game()
In [5]: game.save()

In [6]: instance1 = Instance.objects.create(player=player, game=game, score=0)

In [7]: player.instance_set.all()
Out[7]: [<Instance: Instance object>]

In [8]: game.instance_set.all()
Out[8]: [<Instance: Instance object>]

In [9]: all_scores_for_john_rambo = [i.score for i in player.instance_set.filter(player__name="John Rambo")]
Out[9]: [0]
```

Comment: I think there is already Extra fields in Django M2M Field
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

It do same with extra logic in new model

Comment: Same question as below.